# How to modify jstree to display name of node when seleted

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

In this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ak4Ed/ when a node is selected and the key 'c' is pressed the selected node id is displayed as popup.

How can I modify the code so that when a node is selected the popup is displayed instead of relying on the user pressing the 'c' hotkey ?

Reading the jstree documentation this does not seem to be explained ? : http://www.jstree.com/documentation/core

Here is the jsfiddle code :

```
<div id="demo1" style="height:100px;">
     <ul>
         <li id="node_1_id">
             <a>Root node 1</a>
             <ul>
                 <li id="child_node_1_id">
                     <a>Child node 1</a>
                 </li>
                 <li id="child_node_2_id">
                     <a>Child node 2</a>
                 </li>
             </ul>
         </li>

     </ul>
     <ul>
                    <li><a>Team A's Projects</a>
                        <ul>
                        <li><a>Iteration 1</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a>Story A</a></li>
                                <li><a>Story B</a></li>
                                <li><a>Story C</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            </li>
                        <li><a>Iteration 2</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a>Story D</a></li>
                              </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
 </div>


$(function() {

    $("#demo1").jstree({
                "hotkeys": {
                    "c" : function(event) { 
                        var node = this._get_node();
                        if(!node) {
                            alert("no node selected");   
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("selected node: "+node.attr("id"));
                        }
                    },
                    "d": function(event) {
                        var node = this._get_node(this.data.ui.hovered);
                        if(!node) {
                            alert("no node hovered");    
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("hovered node: "+node.attr("id"));
                        }
                    }
                },
        "plugins": ["ui", "html_data", "themes", "hotkeys"]
    });
});
```

Comment: Selected how? By click? If so, why don't you just use standard jQuery and skip jstree?

Comment: @ryan but I want to render the contents using a tree structure, so how can bypass jstree ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an event `select_node.jstree`. It fires when a node is selected. I didn't find it in the documentation (strange...).

Then to find a selected node you can by class `jstree-clicked`.

I have updated your jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ak4Ed/118/

Comment: @phil.tx thanks, do you mind explaining how you found the select_node.jstree event ?

Comment: just tried "select_node" (like other events from docs with mask "<action>_node") and it worked :)

Comment: This says selected node: undefined?

Comment: because not all  'li' elements have id in this example